# How to run plugin on maven dependency

Tags: maven

I'm setting up a (java) maven project that depends on a library (Jettison, among others) that is in the Maven repo.  Jettison, in turn, depends on stax.  I need to run a tool (Jar Jar Links) on stax (to change the namespace).  How do I alter the rules for a transitive dependency in a maven project?  My transitive dependencies are being included in my target folder using the copy-dependencies goal (I assume this is how things are usually done).  I assume that this is the point where the plugin would be run on the transitively-generated artifact.

Extra question: I don't need this at this point but how would I go about altering the *source* in the transitive dependency?  I can get the jar of the source with `mvn dependency:sources` but, from there, I'm not sure what the right approach is.

Comment: *"My transitive dependencies are being included in my target folder using the copy-dependencies goal (I assume this is how things are usually done)"* actually this is the **anti-pattern** of how Maven dependency management should work.

Comment: I'd never heard of [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) and just read its brief "How does it work?" and I have no idea why anyone would want to use this. Ever. Your question has red flags all over the place, in terms of how one would want to use Maven. I'm getting the impression that there's an underlying problem that you're trying to fix (whatever it is that is prompting you to rename class files in an existing dependency), perhaps you should ask a question about that -- perhaps in terms of Maven being the vehicle for that.

Answer (score -1):

Victory!

Seems at least two people are even more clueless about Maven than me so let me explain what I'm doing before I report the fix at the bottom of this post (spoiler alert: it looks to be a bug in JarJar).

Android uses Java but its missing a lot of the java core (specifically, javax classes).  The Android DEX compiler (which converts .jars to Android .dex files) won't even allow you to compile things in the java.* or javax.* namespace because it'll (usually) break stuff.  However, in some (many) cases, there are routines that you might want to include -- specifically because they are used by existing libraries.  The most legendary is StAX, which is why Google posted an example of how to include it [here in the Dalvik repo's wiki](https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages).  The example uses JarJar... with ant.  Transitive dependencies are not really an issue when you aren't using a repo so they are not addressed in the wiki.

I was able to get JarJar to run on my source with Maven but without changing the namespaces in the dependencies (and transitive dependencies), that's worthless.  Hence my question.

I thought that the copy-dependencies plugin might be useful for... copying the dependencies and running a transforming plugin in the process.  Copying dependencies is mentioned as a step in the official "Maven in 5 minutes" doc so it seemed like a good start but maybe the the people who wrote the official docs don't know how to use it :-) .  Either way, it it didn't help -- there is no simple way I could see to transform the jars as it copies.

Using the verbose spew from Maven, I was able to see that Jar Jar *was* in fact processing my jars properly... and then throwing out the result.  It would have packaged the converted classes from the transitive dependencies in my artifact with the rest of my code but, instead, it "Excluded" them.  Jar Jar parameters are [basically undocumented](http://sonatype.github.io/jarjar-maven-plugin/jarjar-mojo.html) and most of the tags aren't even listed in the docs but all of the examples I could find use a  section with wild-cards that tell it what classes to hold onto.  At least I thought (think?) that's what the section is for.  Instead, it seems to randomly throw out stuff.  Basically, the  section is busted.  For example, I had:

```
            <keep>
              <pattern>com.example.**</pattern>
            </keep>
```

...thinking that this would keep classes that began with com.example.  Wrong.  It keeps whatever the hell it wants.  I tried a million things in that spot until one worked:

```
            <keep>
              <pattern>*.**</pattern>
            </keep>
```

This only keeps the classes I wanted -- the classes it updated and the originals of the ones that it didnt touch.  Note that `**` doesn't even work.  This is version 1.8 of the JarJar plugin (the version most poms Ive found use).

Back to work.